# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't like a HashMap as delegate

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, delegates

Let's consider the following code:

```
class MyClass { //Here:IJ says method putAll not implemented
    @Delegate
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>()
}

hello = new MyClass()
hello.put("x", 1)

println "x=" + hello.get("x")
```

It works fine when called with Groovy directly on the command line, but IntelliJ IDEA complains about the first line with the following error message:
    Method putAll() is not implemented

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: Which and what first line?

Comment: If it compiles and runs, then it's not broken... it's just your IDE getting confused. The dynamic nature of Groovy can give IDEs fits and cause a lot of false-errors. You can either file an issue with Intellij and see if they can fix it.

Comment: I was hoping I was missing something, but it indeed looks as a bug, therefore I have filed a bug report : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-149284

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same behavior.
What I found was in my IntelliJ project, the class (MyClass) was showing with the .groovy file extension in the Project view. By doing a refactor-->Rename and removing the .groovy extension, the class would then show without the extension in the Project view and the issue was resolved.

The explanation for the issue came when I tried to run the class, which is really a Groovy Script and not just a plain Class. When it compiles, it would encounter an error:

Invalid duplicate class definition, which gave me a hint that I had created what IntelliJ saw as a Class definition, but was really a Groovy script, so IntelliJ, behind the scenes processed the script and created a second, synthetic class for the script.